# Get Opportunity ID from a Quote layout custom button

Tags: javascript

```
var quoteId = '{!Quote.Id}';

alert(quoteId);

var oppId = '{!Opportunity.Id}';

alert(oppId);
```

The variable oppid displays blank...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the opportunity id of the quote, you need to look at the quote fields instead:

UPDATED :

- Create a formula field as Text for Opportunity Id, **OpportunityId__c**
- Create custom button using the formula field instead :

`var oppId = '{!Quote.OpportunityId__c}';`

Comment: Error: Field Quote.OpportunityId does not exist. Check spelling

Comment: Interesting that OpportunityId wouldn't be available. Sorry about that. You could definitely try with ajax toolkit.

Comment: Getting error "No such column 'OpportunityID' on entity 'Quote"

Comment: I am using Execute JavaScript on a custom button on for quotes.  Also using you exact sample.

Comment: @TimKolb - sometimes (org-dependent), after one enables Quotes or Orders, some of the fields are not visible to even the System Administrator as running user. Check FLS on the Quote.OpportunityId standard object field

Comment: This really weird indeed... another solution would be to create a formula field that contains the opportunity.id a bit silly but it should work. I don't quite understand why Salesforce wouldn't support this field.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully that will do the job ;)

Comment: Thanks, I see this solution elsewhere also.  Seems like SF has a bug in the API.

Comment: Please find my ans

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the OpportunityId behind the custom button, you need to execute the query explicitly as follows:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")} 

var quoteRec = sforce.connection.query("select Opportunity.Id from Quote where Id='" + '{!Quote.Id}' + "'"); 
var records1 = quoteRec.getArray('records'); 

if(records1 !=null) 
{ 
alert(quoteRec.records.Opportunity.Id); 
}
```